# Rails includes causing incorrect result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I am using includes to do eager loading on my one query. I am trying to query invoices to get the total amount invoiced. I get 2 different results when I use includes vs. when I don't. Can anyone explain why this is happening/how to best fix this?

```
all_invoices = Invoice.includes(:contractor, :invoice_items, :refunds).with_user(1).date_between(date_range).search_contractor("tester").displayed_invoices.order(created_at: 'DESC')

tester = Invoice.with_user(1).date_between(date_range).search_contractor("tester").displayed_invoices.order(created_at: 'DESC')

all_invoices.pluck(:total_in_cents).sum  #this will return 80000

tester.pluck(:total_in_cents).sum #this will return 40000
```

The 2nd one is the correct result of what I"m looking for, but obviously having includes in there is helpful for speed so I'm not trying to remove it, but I need to get the correct result from it.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the code for :total_in_cents?

Comment: :total_in_cents is just a column in my invoices db table. I store the total amount of each invoice as cents in each row for the given invoice

Comment: Sorry i assumed you were doing a calculation before .Sum. do you reuse the : total in cents column name?

Comment: oooo that could be it. There is a total_in_cents on invoice_items and refunds as well. So if it's an ambiguous column name it will sum up for all rows from the included tables where that column name is too? I did not know that.

Comment: I'll test that out to be sure, but do you want to put an answer in with that....thinking about it I think your right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are plucking `:total_in_cents` from two different arrays.

Tester is plucking from `SELECTED from "invoices"`

all_invoices is plucking `from SELECTED from "invoices"`, but also `:contractor, :invoice_items and :refunds` that meet the same criteria as:

`.with_user(1).date_between(date_range).search_contractor("tester")`

I assume some of these are fillers, but that `.with_user` queries a user, and that user probably has some other records related in `:contractor, :invoice_items or refunds`

You could test it by adjusting the column record names, and re-seeding the database or better yet filtering out those records not associated with the 'Invoices'and running the same query